# How I can show the number of items in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, display

In recyclerview, I want only 3 items to show,

so I set the width and height with recyclerview but,

another test device it show 3.2 items to show.

in main activity,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/main_activity_recyclerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and in main_activity_recyclerviews view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" **android:layout_width="90dp"**
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

<TextView> ...


</LinearLayout>
```

In main_activity_recyclerviews view, I change the width and test in A device, it show just 3 items, but test in B device, it shows 3.2items.

It occurs looks like device display size.

How I can show the recyclerview items of appoint size?

----------------------update---------------------------

```
@Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_main,parent,false);

            view.getLayoutParams().height = changeX;

            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }
```

oncreateviewholder

Comment: `3.2` means ???

Comment: Set different values to  width through `dimens` for devices with different dpis

Comment: in your adapter edit your method `getCount()` to return 3

Comment: how can you see 3,2 items if your adapter has only 3 items?

Comment: nono I mean my items size is 15, but when I didn't scroll it, first show items size is 3. 3.2 means I can see 3 items and lie across the border another item 0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set height of each child problematically like

```
view.getLayoutParams().height = getScreenHeight() / VIEWS_COUNT_TO_DISPLAY;
```

And the screen size like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics).heightPixels;
```

Comment: you mean get layout size and divide by VIEWS_COUNT_TO_DISPLAY;
where i put it?
In recyclerviews oncreate?

Comment: in adapters onCreateViewHolder

Comment: My recyclerview in LinearLayout, in that case I get the linearlayout height and divide it?
update my question, please look at that

Comment: you need to get the screen size and divide it into three then set that value to your linearLayout.